# Null DateTime Insert into SQL by Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I want to insert a date or a null value into a date time field(SQL).

But I cannot insert the null value.

I want to do this without SP.

Comment: you set the DBNull  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/q/13683338/853295

Comment: set default value of Date field to null, simple :)

Comment: update the question with the related code

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: check database whether you set "Not NUll" to DateTime field.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd1.Parameters["@DateTimeParamName"].Value = getDate ?? DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `DBNull.Value`  if you using parameters

```
cmd.Parameters["@DateTimeParamName"].Value = DBNull.Value
```